# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f:A→B$ be a function let $h:P(B)→P(A)$ which defined by $h(Q)=f-1 (Q)$ for all $Q\in P(B).$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Let 
$A,B$ be sets and let 
$f:A→B,h:P(B)→P(A)
h(Q):=f−1(Q), ∀Q∈P(B)$
Prove that $h$ is injective iff $f$ is injective.
I know one of the conditions for it to become 
$h$ and $f$ injective. The codmain for the interior 
($h$) must be equal to the domain ($f$)
May I ask for help in proving the statement? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your notation is not clear: what does $f - 1(Q)$ mean? what does "interior" mean here?

Comment: ... I'm guessing now that $f - 1(Q)$ means the inverse image $f^{-1}(Q)$. You write that in MathJax  as f^{-1}(Q). If my guess is right, then the claim that $f$ is injective iff $h$ is injective is incorrect.